# A functional equation relating two harmonic sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series, mellin-transform

**Introduction.** I computed two Mellin transforms while browsing / working on the problem at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117583/). No solution was found, but some interesting auxiliary results appeared. I am writing to ask for independent confirmation of these results, not necessarily using Mellin transforms.

**Problem statement.** Introduce 
$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)} 
\frac{1}{\sinh((2k-1)x)}
\quad\text{and}\quad
T(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k} 
\frac{1}{\sinh(kx)}$$

Prove the functional equation
$$S(x) = \frac{1}{2} S(\pi^2/x)
- \frac{1}{16} x
+ \frac{1}{4} \log 2
+ \frac{3}{4} T(x).$$

Evaluate $T(x)$ at $x=\sqrt{2}\pi$ and prove that
$$T(\sqrt{2}\pi) = \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{12} - \frac{1}{2}\log 2.$$

**Remark.** It is hoped that these two problems might reward investigation, perhaps using several different methods. I do ask that possible details of the computations be included.

Comment: The second formula reminds of that of the [Jacobi $\theta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). Any chance that they might be somehow related, or that similar approaches might apply ?

Comment: Good observation. They are indeed related as you can see when you scroll down the page of the Wikipedia entry to the section where they sketch Riemann's proof of the functional equation of the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $q = e^{-x}$ so that $$T(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sinh nx} = 2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{2n})} = f(q)\text{ (say)}\tag{1}$$ and then we have
\begin{align}
T(x) &= f(q)\notag\\
&= 2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}}{n(1 - q^{2n})}\notag\\
&= 2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}}{n}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}q^{2mn}\notag\\
&= 2\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{(2m + 1)n}}{n}\notag\\
&= -2\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\log(1 - q^{2m + 1})\notag\\
&= -2\log\prod_{m = 1}^{\infty}(1 - q^{2m - 1})\notag\\
&= -2\log\left(2^{1/4}q^{1/24}\left(\frac{2k}{k'^{2}}\right)^{-1/12}\right)\tag{2}\\
&= -\frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log q}{12} + \frac{1}{6}\log\frac{2k}{k'^{2}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
where $k$ is the elliptic modulus corresponding to nome $q$ and $k' = \sqrt{1 - k^{2}}$.

The product $\prod(1 - q^{2m - 1})$ is essentially [Ramanujan's class invariant](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/03/ramanujans-class-invariants.html) $g_{n}, g(q)$ and we have accordingly given its representation $(2)$ in terms of nome $q$ and modulus $k$. Also note that $\log q = -\pi K'/K$ where $K, K'$ are complete elliptic integrals of first kind with modulus $k$ and $k' = \sqrt{1 - k^{2}}$.

By the theory of modular equations (given in the link on Ramanujan's class invariant mentioned earlier) it is known that if $K'/K = \sqrt{r}$ where $r$ is a positive rational number then the value of modulus $k$ is an algebraic number and such value of $k$ is called a *singular modulus* and denoted by $k_{r}$. Here in the current notation we have $\log q = -x$ and hence if $x = \pi\sqrt{r}$ then the value of $k$ is an algebraic number and it is possible to have a closed form for $T(x)$ in terms of logarithm of an algebraic number plus $x/12$.

If we set $x = \pi\sqrt{2}$ then the corresponding value of singular modulus $k$ is $k = k_{2} = \sqrt{2} - 1$. And hence $2k/(1 - k^{2}) = 1$ and it follows from $(3)$ that $$T(\sqrt{2}\pi) = \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{12} - \frac{1}{2}\log 2\tag{4}$$ Next we discuss the sum $S(x)$ given by $$S(x) = \sum_{n\text{ odd}}\frac{1}{n\sinh nx} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sinh nx} - \sum_{n\text{ even}}\frac{1}{n\sinh nx} = T(x) - \frac{T(2x)}{2}\tag{5}$$ Note that when $x$ is replaced by $2x$ then $q = e^{-x}$ is replaced by $q^{2}$ and hence $T(2x) = f(q^{2})$. By Landen's transformation replacing $q$ with $q^{2}$ leads to replacing $k$ with $(1 - k')/(1 + k')$ and hence
\begin{align}
T(2x) &= f(q^{2})\notag\\
&= -\frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log q^{2}}{12} + \frac{1}{6}\log\dfrac{2\cdot\dfrac{1 - k'}{1 + k'}}{1 - \left(\dfrac{1 - k'}{1 + k'}\right)^{2}}\notag\\
&= -\frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log q}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\log\frac{1 - k'^{2}}{2k'}\notag\\
&= -\frac{\log 2}{2} - \frac{\log q}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\log\frac{k^{2}}{2k'}\tag{6}
\end{align}
and hence it follows from $(3), (5)$ and $(6)$ that $$S(x) = -\frac{\log 2}{4} + \frac{1}{12}\log\frac{8}{k'^{3}}\tag{7}$$ Note that the above equation shows that for $x = \pi\sqrt{r}, r\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ the value of $S(x)$ is the logarithm of an algebraic number.

Next we deal with the transformation from $x$ to $\pi^{2}/x$. This changes $q = e^{-x}$ to $q' = e^{-\pi^{2}/x}$ and the effect of this is to swap $k$ and $k'$ so that $$S(\pi^{2}/x) = -\frac{\log 2}{4} + \frac{1}{12}\log\frac{8}{k^{3}}\tag{8}$$ and from $(7)$ and $(8)$ we get $$S(x) - (1/2)S(\pi^{2}/x) = -\frac{\log 2}{8} + \frac{1}{8}\log \frac{2k}{k'^{2}}\tag{9}$$ and looking at equations $(3)$ and $(9)$ we get $$S(x) = \frac{1}{2}S\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{x}\right) - \frac{1}{16}x + \frac{1}{4}\log 2 + \frac{3}{4}T(x)\tag{10}$$ which is the desired functional equation connecting $S(x), S(\pi^{2}/x)$ and $T(x)$.

---

Like most of my answers dealing with sums involving hyperbolic functions this answer also requires a good understanding of the theory of elliptic integrals and their link with theta functions and other related topics.

Incidentally Ramanujan delved very deep into these topics and he had a very good understanding of both Mellin transform (favorite tool used by OP, see his answers) and elliptic/theta functions and moreover he somehow had the real-analysis equivalent of Mellin transform methods (Ramanujan's Master Theorem) so he could achieve his results without any use of complex analysis.

Comment: where did you learn all this stuff about elliptic integrals, modular invariants etc. i don't like the sources i found so far...

Comment: @tired: Well, I have learnt the theory from many sources over a considerable amount of time and given a description of my sources in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793756/72031 (see the update section of this answer). A coherent and systematic presentation of whatever I know about this topic is available on my blog https://paramanands.blogspot.com/p/archives.html

Comment: cool, thx a million. the theory surronding elliptic integrals is something i want to learn next...(+1) by the way

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we seek a functional equation for

$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)} 
\frac{1}{\exp(x(2k-1))-\exp(-x(2k-1))}.$$

(The factor of two that is missing is due to the sum that appeared in the 
post that I linked to in the introduction.)

The  sum $S(x)$  is harmonic  and may  be evaluated  by inverting  its
Mellin transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = \frac{1}{(2k-1)}, 
\quad \mu_k = 2k-1 \quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \frac{1}{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$
which is computed as follows:
$$g^*(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)} x^{s-1} dx
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\exp(-x)}{1-\exp(-2x)} x^{s-1} dx
\\ = \int_0^\infty \sum_{q\ge 0} \exp(-(2q+1)x)  x^{s-1} dx
= \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{(2q+1)^s} \Gamma(s)
= \left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) \Gamma(s) \zeta(s).$$

Hence the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of $S(x)$ is given by
$$ Q(s) = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) 
\Gamma(s) \zeta(s) \zeta(s+1)
\\ \quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+1}}\right) \zeta(s+1)$$
where $\Re(s) > 1$.

Intersecting the  fundamental strip and  the half-plane from  the zeta
function  term we  find  that  the Mellin  inversion  integral for  an
expansion about zero is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds$$
which we evaluate in the left half-plane $\Re(s)<3/2.$

The two  zeta function  terms cancel the  poles of the  gamma function
term and we are left with just

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=1) & = \frac{\pi^2}{16x}  \quad\text{and}\\
\mathrm{Res}(Q(s)/x^s; s=0) & = -\frac{1}{4} \log 2.
\end{align}$$

This shows that
$$S(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{16x} -\frac{1}{4} \log 2
+ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-1/2-i\infty}^{-1/2+i\infty} Q(s)/x^s ds.$$

To  treat the  integral recall  the duplication  formula of  the gamma
function:
$$\Gamma(s) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi} 2^{s-1} 
\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right).$$

which yields for $Q(s)$

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) 
\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi} 2^{s-1} 
\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)
\zeta(s) \zeta(s+1)$$

Furthermore observe  the following variant of  the functional equation
of the Riemann zeta function:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s)
= \pi^{s-1/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)
\zeta(1-s)$$

which gives for $Q(s)$
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) 
\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi} 2^{s-1} 
\pi^{s-1/2}
\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)
\zeta(1-s)\zeta(s+1)
\\ = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) 
\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi} 2^{s-1} 
\pi^{s-1/2}
\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi(s+1)/2)}
\zeta(1-s)\zeta(s+1)
\\ = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s+1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right) 
2^{s-1}
\frac{\pi^s}{\sin(\pi(s+1)/2)}
\zeta(1-s)\zeta(s+1).$$

Now put $s=-u$ in the remainder integral to get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{1/2-i\infty}^{1/2+i\infty} 
\left(1-\frac{2^u}{2}\right)
\left(1-2^u\right) 
2^{-u-1}
\frac{\pi^{-u}}{\sin(\pi(-u+1)/2)}
\zeta(1+u)\zeta(1-u) x^u du
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{1/2-i\infty}^{1/2+i\infty} 
\left(1-\frac{2^u}{2}\right)
\left(1-2^u\right) 
2^{-u-1}
\\ \times \frac{\pi^{u}}{\sin(\pi(-u+1)/2)}
\zeta(1+u)\zeta(1-u) (x/\pi^2)^u du.$$

We may shift this to $3/2$ as there is no pole at $u=1.$

Now $$\sin(\pi(-u+1)/2) = \sin(\pi(-u-1)/2+\pi)
\\ = - \sin(\pi(-u-1)/2) = \sin(\pi(u+1)/2)$$

and furthermore
$$\left(1-\frac{2^u}{2}\right)
\left(1-2^u\right) 
2^{-u-1}
= \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\frac{2^u}{2}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{2^u}-1\right) 
= 2^{u-2} \left(\frac{1}{2^{u-1}}-1\right)
\left(\frac{1}{2^u}-1\right) 
\\ = 2^{u-2} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{u-1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^u}\right)
\\ = 2^{u-2} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{u+1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^u}\right)
- 3\times 2^{u-2} \frac{1}{2^{u+1}}
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^u}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} 2^{u-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{u+1}}\right)
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^u}\right)
- \frac{3}{4} 2^{u-1} 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^u}\right) \frac{1}{2^{u}}.$$

We have shown that
$$S(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{16x} -\frac{1}{4} \log 2
+ \frac{1}{2} S(\pi^2/x)
\\ - \frac{3}{4} \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} 
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^u}\right) 
\Gamma(u) \zeta(u) \zeta(u+1)
(x/\pi^2/2)^u du$$

or alternatively

$$S(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{16x} -\frac{1}{4} \log 2
+ \frac{1}{2} S(\pi^2/x)
- \frac{3}{4} T(2\pi^2/x)$$

where 
$$T(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k} 
\frac{1}{\exp(kx)-\exp(-kx)}$$

with functional equation
$$T(x) = \frac{1}{24} x - \frac{1}{2}\log 2
+ \frac{\pi^2}{12x} - T(2\pi^2/x).$$

which finally yields
$$S(x) = \frac{1}{2} S(\pi^2/x)
- \frac{1}{32} x
+ \frac{1}{8} \log 2
+ \frac{3}{4} T(x).$$

Using $\sinh$ with
$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)} 
\frac{1}{\sinh((2k-1)x)}
\quad\text{and}\quad
T(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k} 
\frac{1}{\sinh(kx)}$$

we obtain the functional equation
$$S(x) = \frac{1}{2} S(\pi^2/x)
- \frac{1}{16} x
+ \frac{1}{4} \log 2
+ \frac{3}{4} T(x).$$

We also have
$$T(\sqrt{2}\pi) =
\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{24} - \frac{1}{2}\log 2
+ \frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{24}
= \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{12} - \frac{1}{2}\log 2.$$