# More on Eisenstein-like series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

**Context:**
This post is related to [Conjectured closed forms for Eisenstein-like series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747956/conjectured-closed-forms-for-eisenstein-like-series) . This is an  extension of it.
We have also:
\begin{align*}
S(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)\left(e^{\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2x}}\left(\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2x})}\cos{(\frac{\pi n}{x})}+\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2x})}\sin{(\frac{\pi n}{x})}\right)+1 \right)}{e^{\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{x}}+2e^{\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2x}}\left(\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2x})}\cos{(\frac{\pi n}{x})}+\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2x})}\sin{(\frac{\pi n}{x})} \right)+1}=\frac{1}{24},\tag{1}
\end{align*}
for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$.
For $x=1$, the sum reduces to:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)}{e^{\pi(2n-1)}+1}=\frac{1}{24}, \tag{2}
\end{align*}
which is well known and in the linked question we can find a proof. Also several different proofs here [Proof of $\frac{1}{e^{\pi}+1}+\frac{3}{e^{3\pi}+1}+\frac{5}{e^{5\pi}+1}+\ldots=\frac{1}{24}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389146/proof-of-frac1e-pi1-frac3e3-pi1-frac5e5-pi1-ldots?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For $x=2$, the sum is:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n-1)\left( e^{\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{4}}\left( \cos{(\frac{\pi n}{2})+\sin{(\frac{\pi n}{2})}} \right) +\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{2}}+2e^{\frac{\pi(2n-1)}{4}}\left(\cos{(\frac{\pi n}{2})+\sin{(\frac{\pi n}{2})}} \right)+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{24}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Deal with $(1)$ seems to be possible as Paramanand Singh dealt with the previous and this is so close.
I have a systematic way to obtain sums for which $S(x)=S(x+1)$ when $x$ is a positive integer.

**Question:** Is there an elementary way (avoiding modular forms) for proving $S(x)=S(x+1)$ when $x$ is a positive integer for functions like $S(x)$?

Comment: The above problem is similar to the one in your previous post. Use the values $\tau=i/4x,u=(i+1)/4x,v=(i-1)/4x$ and $q=\exp(2\pi i\tau) $ and the sum in question is $\frac{q} {2}\frac{d}{dq}\log\prod_{n\geq 1}(1+\exp((2n-1)2\pi iu))(1+\exp((2n-1)2\pi iv))$ and one can then express it in terms of $E_2$.

Comment: The key part here in such evaluations is that $(i+1)(i-1)=-2$ and more importantly $(i+1)^2+(i-1)^2=0$ which permits closed form without evaluation of $E_2(ix)$.

Comment: Perhaps you should also discuss your approach to generate such sums which are constant at integers.

Comment: Hi @ParamanandSingh as soon as possible I will improve the question with the way I obtain sums that are constant at positive integers.