Deriving the value of the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left[\frac{2n}{e^{2\pi n}+1}+\frac{2n-1}{e^{\left(2n-1\right)\pi }-1}\right]$
I have been working on trying to show that
$\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left[\frac{2n}{e^{2\pi n}+1}+\frac{2n-1}{e^{\left(2n-1\right)\pi }-1}\right]=\frac{\varpi ^2}{4\pi ^2}-\frac{1}{8}$
where $\displaystyle \varpi =\frac{\Gamma ^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{2\sqrt{2\pi }}$ is the lemniscate constant.
Note the individual even and odd indexed series resolve to
$\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2n}{e^{2\pi n}+1}=\frac{\varpi ^2}{8\pi ^2}-\frac{1}{12}$
and
$\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2n-1}{e^{\left(2n-1\right)\pi }-1}=\frac{\varpi ^2}{8\pi ^2}-\frac{1}{24}$
I have seen evaluations of similar series like $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n}{e^{2\pi n}-1}$ using inverse Mellin transform and I have tried to set this up by using the Mellin transforms of $\displaystyle \frac{x}{e^{\pi x}+1}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{x}{e^{\pi x}-1}$, then taking the inversion and summing over even or odd positive integers.
For example in the even indexed series (similar issues arise in the odd one), I get to
$\displaystyle S_{even} = \frac{1}{2\pi ^3i}\int _{c-i\infty }^{c+i\infty }\left(1-2^{-s}\right)\sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma \left(1+s\right)\Gamma \left(1-s\right)\zeta \left(1+s\right)\zeta \left(1-s\right)ds$
The integrand has simple poles at $s=-1,1$ and a double pole at $s=0$. I tried to set up a contour by closing in the $\displaystyle \left[c-iR,c+iR\right]$ with a semicircle of radius R centered at $c$ for $c > 1$. After calculating residues, I get $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{24}$ which is definitely wrong and I'm not sure if the circle part vanishes as $R\to\infty$.
I have also seen cases where rectangular contours that have a line on the imaginary axis are used and the function is found odd at $s=0$ so that contribution as well as those on horizontal lines vanish. However, this integrand for the even indexed series is not odd at $s=0$ or any obvious point on the real line that I could use.
I don't know how I can resolve this by picking a better contour or any other manipulations to arrive at the desired result. Help is greatly appreciated.

The sums belong to theory of elliptic integrals and theta functions and are based on closed form evaluation of the Ramanujan function $P(q) = 1-24\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{nq^n}{1-q^n}$.

I did recognize this specific kind of Lambert series is another connection that could help for an alternate way to arrive at the solution, but I couldn't find out how to get the proper form or like $q$ as a constant without extra factors depending on $n$.

Let $f(q) =\sum \frac{nq^n} {1-q^n}=\frac{1-P(q)}{24}$ and $g(q) =\sum\frac{nq^n} {1+q^n} $ so that $f(q) - g(q) =2f(q^2)$ and $\sum\frac{2nq^{2n}}{1+q^{2n}}=2g(q^2) =2f(q^2) - 4f(q^4)=\frac{2P(q^4)-P(q^2)}{12}-\frac{1}{12}$. This gives you the sum with even index when $q=e^{-\pi} $. The second sum (which again equals $g(q) $) with odd index can be dealt in same manner with slightly less effort.

@ParamanandSingh I'm running into issues with the odd indexed series because of the lingering $e^{\pi}$ factor in the denominator from $1-e^{-(2n-1)\pi}$ if I multiply top and bottom by $e^{-(2n-1)\pi}$. And if I split the sum up by the difference $2n-1$, I'm not sure if the sum taking the $-1$ can be expressed as a derivative or other expression in terms of $P(q)$ when missing that $n$ in the numerator.

Nevermind I forgot I can get the odd series from the series over all naturals minus the even series.

I have found sources on StackExchange like here where for $q=e^{-\pi \frac{k^{\prime }}{k}}$ we have $P\left(q\right)=\frac{12E\left(k\right)K\left(k\right)+\left(4k^2-8\right)K^2\left(k\right)}{\pi ^2}$ in terms of elliptic integrals, but I'm not sure of how to prove this and couldn't find references in like Ramanujan's Lost notebook or others.

Well if you really want to get to the proofs you will need to study some amount of theory of elliptic integrals and theta functions. I have covered these topics in my blog posts (see archive page and search for "elliptic" and "theta") but it does require some patience to assimilate all the details.

You may also have a look at this answer of mine which is based on same ideas: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1695377/72031
